# Mailing with laravel (send data to php)

Tags: laravel, email, variables

im pretty new to mailing with laravel and have just a quick question but can't really find anything on it the way I did it.

I want to send data to my mail php file. The mail sends but only with static html. I can't find out how to send variables.

In Mailcontroller

```
public function sendNewsletter(Request $request){

    $users = User::where('newsletter', '=', 1)->get();


    foreach ($users as $user){


        \Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Newsletter);
    }
    return redirect(route('admin.news'));
}
```

In Newsletter.php inside App/Mail folder

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.newsletter');
}
```

Comment: I hope that's in a queue. It will kill the server if it's not. Check the manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [views doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views).

You can pass variables to your view using an array as second parameter.

```
return $this->view('emails.newsletter', ['variableName' => $variable]);
```

You can then access the passed variables directly from your view using the Blade syntax:

```
{{ $variableName }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass via public properties or use with()
I personally use the public properties way. 
It's pretty straight forward.

Read this section of the mail docs for laravel

[View-data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#view-data)